# In the policy gradient method, state dependent baseline does not affect gradient of the objective function. Then how this is better approach?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients

In policy gradient theory subtracting state dependent baseline from Q(s,a) does not affect gradient of the objective function. I understand the proof shown below. One things is, if it's not affecting the gradient, then how this approach is better?
[image: Proof that state dependent baseline does not affect gradient of the objective funtion]

Comment: Short answer: variance reduction. Some details may be found, e.g., [here](https://danieltakeshi.github.io/2017/03/28/going-deeper-into-reinforcement-learning-fundamentals-of-policy-gradients/).

Comment: @mikkola thank you for your time end effort sir. I will check this out.